# Declaration of Structure in multiple header files

Tags: c, struct, clang, header-files

If I define a structure in a.c then how can I access that structure in multiple header files say a.h, b.h, and c.h?

Let say a.c looks like:

```
typedef struct task
{
int a;
char b;
}task;
```

How can I declare the above structure in a.h and b.h

I have tried using **extern struct task** but in .h file, it says "extern ignored on this declaration".

Comment: Copy this text `typedef struct task
{
int a;
char b;
}task;` into a.h file. Copy the same text into b.h file.

Comment: include a.h into the b.h

Comment: @KamilCuk, so there is no way to define it in a header file?

Comment: That is what is being said: define it in the header file, not in the .c file. That is (one reason) what header files are for.

Comment: @WeatherVane ok so if I define the struct in a header file and not in the c file then if I want to access it in the c file, I should just use "a.h" and if in another header file then I should use the complete struct, right?

Comment: Include that header file before you include another header file that needs it – for example in a function declaration (prototype). Or as said, include one header file in another, but you can get in trouble unless using "header guards".

Comment: @OwaisQayyum you need to read a C book. `#include` directives are described there in details

Comment: so who's going to write the answer?